# UI Testing if a button is enabled

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to check if a `Button` is disabled in my UI test.

In Android you would normally do something like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.buttonId)).check(matches(not(isEnabled())));
```

What is the equivalent when writing a UI test for Flutter?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Give your `Button` a `UniqueKey` and pump the Widget and perform other test clicks, etc. Then

```
expect(tester.widget<FlatButton>(find.byKey(buttonKey)).enabled, isFalse);
```

Comment: The `.enabled` does not exist for FlatButton. What should I do?

Comment: I believe in flutter a button is enabled if it's onPressed attribute is not null. Therefore you could simply check if this attribute is not null